# "Fodder" meaning "useless chatter"?

Tags: meaning, nouns

Is there a usage of the word *fodder* that means "useless chatter"? I have used it this way in the past but can't find it referenced that way currently.

Comment: Fodder for conversation is generally where you're talking about something specific, and it can be useless, idle chatter, but fodder by itself does not mean chatter.

Comment: Since fodder is food fed to fatten cattle, it’s a perfectly understandable extended use for feeding into the rumor mill or chat column. But it isn’t just random prattle without further qualification.

Comment: "Fodder" is something being fed.  If it's not being fed, literally or figuratively (to an animal, the rumor mill, cannons, etc), then it's likely just trash or junk or some such.

Answer (score 1):

I wonder if you were thinking of ***folderol***:

> mere nonsense; foolish talk or ideas.
>   <sub>*from [dictionary.com](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/falderal)*</sub>

The word is also seen as *falderal* or *falderol*.

Answer (score 0):

**"Fodder for the rumor mill"** is a phrase with some usage ([16k google hits](https://www.google.co.uk/?gws_rd=ssl#q=%22fodder%20for%20the%20rumor%20mill%22)).

[Fodder](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/fodder) literally means:

> 1. food, especially hay or straw, for animals such as cows and horses

But is often used figuratively in the same way as "food" is:

> 2. someone or something considered useful only for one particular purpose:
>      *We are not just voting fodder for professional politicians*
> 3. someone or something that people talk or write about:
>      *The band has given plenty of fodder to tabloid journalists*

So "fodder for the rumor mill", if you take rumors as being useless chatter, would mean topics/information for useless chatter.